# Can't get navigation menus to center

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I have this black bar at the top with my navigation menus in it. But if i add "text-align: center" instead of "float: right" then the menus/links go to the center but not in the black bar at the top. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        *
         {
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
         }
         header {
             background-color: black;
             height: 85px;
             line-height: 85px;
         }
         ul {
             list-style: none;
         }
         ul li {
             position: relative;
             display: inline-block;
             font-size: 17px;
         }
         header nav {
             position: relative;
             float: right;
         }
         header nav ul li a {
             padding-right: 20px;
             font-weight: bold;
             text-decoration: none;
             color: #DCDCDC;
         }

         header nav ul li a:hover {
             color: white;
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <a href="" class="logo"><img src="mylogo.png"></a>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">home1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">home2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">home3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">home4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">home5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">home6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: flex` and `justify-content:center` to the `.row` class. Add css values for the logo. I added `position: absolute` and `left: 0` to the logo. If you want to have your logo also aligned horizontally to the center, then remove the css that I added for `.logo`.

Here's a working snippet:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        *
         {
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
         }
         
         .row {
           display: flex;
           justify-content: center;
         }
         header {
             background-color: black;
             height: 85px;
             line-height: 85px;
         }
         .logo {
           position: absolute;
           left: 0;
         }
         ul {
             list-style: none;
         }
         ul li {
             position: relative;
             display: inline-block;
             font-size: 17px;
         }
         header nav {
             position: relative;
             float: right;
         }
         header nav ul li a {
             padding-right: 20px;
             font-weight: bold;
             text-decoration: none;
             color: #DCDCDC;
         }

         header nav ul li a:hover {
             color: white;
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <a href="" class="logo"><img src="mylogo.png"></a>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">home1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">home2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">home3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">home4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">home5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">home6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Great explination

Comment: No problem. I recommend you to take a look into `Flexbox`. Float is ugly nowadays.

Comment: I definitely will :)

Answer (score 0):

To align Element in Center use CSS flexbox, It is the Easiest way to align items
To center them horizontally use justify-content: center;
Just change the display of your div to flex and its inner content will be centered horizontally

```css
.flexbox{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
    <!----Your data you want in Center-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The float: right applies to the element it is attached to, but text-align: center acts on the contents of the element. So you need to move the text-align to the header:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            *
             {
                 margin: 0;
                 padding: 0;
             }
             header {
                 background-color: black;
                 height: 85px;
                 line-height: 85px;
                 text-align: center
             }
             ul {
                 list-style: none;
             }
             ul li {
                 position: relative;
                 display: inline-block;
                 font-size: 17px;
             }
             header nav {
                 position: relative;

             }
             header nav ul li a {
                 padding-right: 20px;
                 font-weight: bold;
                 text-decoration: none;
                 color: #DCDCDC;
             }

             header nav ul li a:hover {
                 color: white;
             }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="mylogo.png"></a>
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">home1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">home2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">home3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">home4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">home5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">home6</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```